# How can I set auto accept for an invitation to a team in GitHub

Tags: github

When I invite GitHub users to a team, some users accept invitation automatically but others are not. 
How can I change the setting for accepting invitation?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can't, because you don't have the credential of the user whom you want to accept your invitations.